# What version of TensorFlow has the `__version__` attribute for tensorflow.keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am debugging an old R file containing a shiny application that utilizes python packages. I installed the packages based on what I was told (`tensorflow`, `keras`, `h5py`) for `Python3.8.10` using `pip` because there is no `requirements.txt`. However I am getting the following error:

```
Error in eval(ei, envir) :
  AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
Calls: runApp ... py_get_attr_or_item -> py_get_attr -> py_get_attr_impl
Execution halted
```

I can confirm that this application was working before, which leads to believe that this error is because I am using the wrong version of tensorflow. Hence my question: What version of TensorFlow has the `__version__` attribute for `tensorflow.keras`

These are my versions of Tensorflow and Keras in case it helps

```
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.13.0'

>>> keras.__version__
'2.13.1'

>>> tf.keras.__version__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'keras.api._v2.keras' has no attribute '__version__'
```

Comment: You are asking the wrong question, you have a XY problem, see https://xyproblem.info/ The question should be which version of tensorflow you had when this was working, not a version that has the attribute you look for, as there could be other incompatibilities.

Comment: Yes, you're correct, but I don't know which version of tensorflow was used, nor was it clarified to me. The documentation with the application is poor, how would I find out which version of tensorflow was used, using just the code that was executed?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `tensorflow==2.12.0`.